# Is there any way to make a custom table view cell look like a button in Xcode 6+?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, evernote, uitableview

I'm trying to create a Table View Cell array and have the name displayed in each table. The tables will look like what you see on the home screen of the Evernote app (shortcut, tags, places, notebooks etc.) and each one will access the next screen when tapped. How do I go about doing this? Novice app developer.

This is an image of the result I'm trying to get.

[image]

Comment: You don't create a array of tableViewCell, you just create one tableViewCell model and reuse it, in this case you have 2 icons and 1 label, just create a reusable cell like that, safe the values of the icons and label in a array of dictionary and use it to update each cell you will need

Comment: Fallow this tutorial is a very good and easy one http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: As a quick and dirty hack I've used in the past for that effect, put each cell into its own section of the UITableView using the grouped table style.

Comment: @Neal could you elaborate. I've got my array in the table view and it shows up when building, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to display as it does in the first image. Putting them in a group puts them all in one cell. I need each of them to be in their own separate cell

Answer (score 2):

That is a basic cell with transparent background and other views (and images, layers, etc.) added as subviews.

For the other things I suggest to study how `UITableView` works and how to push a `UIViewController` using a `UINavigationController`.

In general you should study `iOS` and `Objective-C` from zero.